# Squid proxy server is not working on youtube, instagram, facebook, google, twitter, etc

Tags: http-proxy

I have just bought a VPS and installed squid proxy on it, all good, the proxy is working, but not on youtube, instagram, facebook, etc.. what to do? what to change in squid.conf ?

Comment: I have same question too! no answer?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution:
Check your squid config for `dns_v4_first off` and change it to `dns_v4_first on`. Restart squid and it should work now.

Comment: my squid proxy not working with command. please share your squid config file